# Element(button) could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium

So i am trying to open up a website and then navigating to a certain page that contains the page from which i have to **scrape** the data . i am able to give the input but before reaching the final submit button i get the error "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view". any ideas ?

i have tried to introduce the wait method but still it doesn't give useful results rather slows the site . down below is the code .

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()

ok=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#dropdownlistContentdrpState > input').send_keys('Chandigarh')
#time.sleep(5)
ok2=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#dropdownlistContentdrpSchoolManagement > input').send_keys('Pvt. Unaided')
#driver.refresh()
time.sleep(10)
ok3=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnSearch')
ok3.click()
time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Is it visible in UI when selenium tries to click on it ? or do you have to manually do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error `"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view"` implies that the element which your program was trying to interact with could not be scrolled into view.

To overcome that you can introduce `WebDriverWait` and click or use `element.location_once_scrolled_into_view` first and then click on the element.

Or you can use `Javascript's executor` to click on the element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#btnSearch"))).click()
```

OR

```
ok3=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnSearch')
ok3.location_once_scrolled_into_view
ok3.click()
```

OR

```
ok3=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnSearch')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ok3)
```