# Selenium webdriver finds elements from the previous page, not the current

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a YouTube search, click on a search result, and then follow the recommended videos on the right-hand side. The code I wrote goes to youtube, makes the search, and clicks on a video and the video gets opened up on the browser. However, I cannot bring it to click on one of the recommended videos.

The problem seems to be that, when I use `recommended_videos = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")` to get a list of elements of recommended videos from the right, what I get instead is a list from the previous page (when I first type in the word and get search results).

The code does work properly when I go directly to a video link with `driver.get(url)`, instead of doing a search first.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random

seed = 1
random.seed(seed)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.youtube.com/")

element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input")

# Put the word "history" in the search box and hit enter
element.send_keys("history")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

# Get a list of elements (videos) that get returned by the search
search_results = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")

# Click randomly on one of the first five results
search_results[random.randint(0,4)].click()

# Go to the end of the page (I don't know if this is necessary
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
html.send_keys(Keys.END)

time.sleep(10)

# Get the recommended videos the same way as above. This is where the problem starts, because recommended_videos essentially becomes the same thing as the previous page's search_results, even though the browser is in a new page now.

recommended_videos = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title") 

recommended_videos[random.randint(0,4)].click()
```

So when I click (last line), I get the error

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" href="/watch?v=1oean5l__Cc"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element(button) could not be scrolled into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074623/elementbutton-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random

seed = 1
random.seed(seed)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input")

# Put the word "history" in the search box and hit enter
element.send_keys("history")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

# Get a list of elements (videos) that get returned by the search
search_results = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")

# Click randomly on one of the first five results
search_results[random.randint(0,10)].click()

# Go to the end of the page (I don't know if this is necessary

#
time.sleep(4)

# Get the recommended videos the same way as above. This is where the problem starts, because recommended_videos essentially becomes the same thing as the previous page's search_results, even though the browser is in a new page now.
while True:
    recommended_videos = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='dismissable']/div/a")
    print(recommended_videos)
    recommended_videos[random.randint(1,4)].click()
    time.sleep(4)
```

i am also completely new and thank you for giving me interest in selenium. may this code helps you. change the driver to firefox if you want.

Comment: Thank you, this actually works perfectly! I still do not understand what was wrong with what I did, please let me know if you know why. Thanks!